# Odd Masonry Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery-masonry

I have this photo gallery test page: http://www.fryeburgfair.org/Photo-Test

I am trying to get the images (all the same width, and symetrical in height) to layout nicely.

I am using Masonry for this, all looks good, except in some cases the last image in the set ends up centered in the screen at the bottom row instead of left aligned, does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fix this issue?

To clarify, I mainly have this issue when the screen width is over 1500 pixels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last image is actually not really centered. The first two big images cover a few pixels more than two rows, thats why the last image is shifted to the third column.

Comment: Ah, nice.  To my eye (even zoomed in) they looked like they lined up.  I modified the height of my portrait images by .01% and it works good now. (will accept this as soon as the site allows)